# xarray.dataset.where() does not seem to work for extreme values

Tags: python

I have an hourly rainfall data want to find values corresponding to an hourly extreme rainfall.

I tried to use where() function but does not seem to give me what i want.

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('./precip.nc')

precip = ds['cp']

rainfall=precip.where(ds.cp> 10, drop=True)
```

Comment: How can we help you if we can't see your data?  What did you expect, and what did you get?'

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you need to do? Also, it would help if you could include a few rows of sample data.

Comment: @Hiran Hasanka and Tim Roberts issue I've only just started using this site, therefore I'm having trouble posting further details. My data, however, is in the NETCDF format and consists of 8 hours from 0 UTC to 21 UTC with a 3 hourly difference; each hour has a precipitation value. My current goal is to find out what time of day has the heaviest rainfall.